# SQL Query .. How to look for date in specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MS SQL Table and one of the rows in the table has specific dates. Example: 2019-11-30 22:00:21.000

I am looking to build a SQL Query that will go to my table and only print the results if the date in this specific column is between TODAY + 30 days

Here is what I have but no joy so far

```
SELECT FOOD_TYPE, BEST_BEFORE 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE BESTBEFORE < GETDATE() - 30;
```

It does not complain about the syntax but does not show results either

Comment: You say your bestbefore needs to be between 'TODAY + 30 days' but then your filter is indicating the last 30 days. Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use BETWEEN and CAST as DATE otherwise it won't pick up today's date:

```
SELECT FOOD_TYPE, BEST_BEFORE 
FROM TABLE 
where BEST_BEFORE between cast(getdate() as date) 
    and dateadd(day, 30, cast(getdate() as date))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try:

```
SELECT FOOD_TYPE, BEST_BEFORE 
FROM TABLE 
where BESTBEFORE < dateadd(day, 30, getdate())
```

This query will return all records in `TABLE` if the `BESTBEFORE` column is less than the current date plus 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `BETWEEN` filter. Keep in mind that `GETDATE()` is `DATETIME` (with time value), you might need to convert to `DATE` if you want complete days (as in my example). Also, using `BETWEEN` means that both limits you are comparing to are inclusive.

```
SELECT FOOD_TYPE, BEST_BEFORE 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE BESTBEFORE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() + 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you want:

```
SELECT FOOD_TYPE, BEST_BEFORE 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE BESTBEFORE < DATEADD(day, 30, GETDATE());
```

Note that `GETDATE()` has a time component and I'm guessing that `BESTBEFORE` does not.  The time component should not affect this query.  In addition, this version is "sargable" meaning that the query can use an index on `BEST_BEFORE`.

Answer (score 0):

You must try this SQL Query. It completes your requirement.

```
SELECT T.FOOD_TYPE, T.BEST_BEFORE 
FROM TABLE T with(nolock)
where T.BESTBEFORE Between getdate() AND dateadd(day, 30, getdate())
```

Let me know if question!